# Adding mysql database credentials to environment variable results in operational error

Tags: mysql, django, heroku

I'm deploying a Django web app with Heroku. I have a MySql database.

When my settings.py file contains a hardcoded password and username for the MySQL database, everything works.

I decided to store my username and password in environment variables and rewrote the settings.py file, as shown below.

```
DB_USER = os.environ.get('DB_USER')
DB_PASS = os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD')

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        #'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        #'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'pahlisch',
        'USER': DB_USER,
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASS,
        'HOST': '123.mysql.database.azure.com',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {'sql_mode': 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES'}
    }
}
```

Next, I added my local environment variables to Heroku.

When I attempt to load the site, I get the following message.

(1045, "Access denied for user ''mattrw2'@'44.167.157.221' (using password: NO)")

I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: It is possible that the space char between `:` and `DB_PASS` is assumed to be a part of a value. Try `'PASSWORD':DB_PASS,`, without a space. From the other side the server claims that you do NOT use a password (`(using password: NO)`)... it is strange.

Answer (score 0):

The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-connecting.html) shows that this kind of an error means that, contrary to what you are stating, you did not supply a password.

I suggest you test whether your environment variables are actually stored and accessible. Try to log into the `shell` from `manage.py` and see if you can access your environment variables.